# How to add browser click into Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to add browser click on my google api map. I am using reverse geocode. I will write the coordinates and i want to choose an image from my computer. After i choose image i will submit the coordinate and that image will appear in that coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would add a click event on your map and get the clicked location

```js
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), {
    center : { lat: 37.5, lng: -120 },
    zoom   : 6
})

google.maps.event.addListener(myMap, "click", function(e) {
    var latLng = e.latLng

    // do something with latLng
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an overlay using this image an put this overlay in coordinates that you want. You should use js library to achieve that.